# Doubt with Notation on Conditional Expected Value Demonstration

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I´m having trouble writing a demonstration for the Conditional Expected Value using $\sigma$-algebra. I know its really simple and actually logic but I just can´t find the way to write it. Hope anyone can help me. Let X, Y $\in$ $L^1$($\Omega$, $\mathscr F$, P) and $\mathscr G$ $\subset$ $\mathscr F$ we need to prove that E[X|{ $\emptyset$, $\Omega$ }]= E[X]. Using the $\sigma$-algebra notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X|\{ \emptyset, \Omega \}]$ is defined as the a.s. unique random variable in $\sigma(\{ \emptyset, \Omega \})$ such that for any set $A\in\sigma(\{ \emptyset, \Omega \})$, $E[E[X|\{ \emptyset, \Omega \}];A]=E[X;A]$. $\sigma(\{ \emptyset, \Omega \})$ is just $\{ \emptyset, \Omega \}$ and any r.v. measurable wrt this collection is a.s. constant. Take $A=\Omega$ to conclude that this constant must be $E[X].$